# titanium httpclient exception bad request

Tags: xmlhttprequest, titanium

this is my code, I want to send a request, the url is useful

```
var go_login;
go_login = function(e) {
  var params, xhr;
  xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
  xhr.open("post", Setting.server+"/interface/about_us");
  xhr.onload = function() {
    console.info(this.responseText);
    if (this.status === "200") {
      console.info("successful");
    } else {
      console.info(this.status + "--------------------" + this.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.onerror = function(e) {
    console.info(e.error);
  };
  params = {
    mobile_phone: $.login_phone.value,
    password: $.login_password.value
  };
  return xhr.send(params);
};
```

and this is my error :

[ERROR] TiHttpClient: (TiHttpClient-1) [5706,6457] HTTP Error (org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException): Bad Request
[ERROR] TiHttpClient: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
[ERROR] TiHttpClient:   at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$LocalResponseHandler.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:275)
[ERROR] TiHttpClient:   at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$LocalResponseHandler.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:219)
[ERROR] TiHttpClient:   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
[ERROR] TiHttpClient:   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:637)
[ERROR] TiHttpClient:   at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1329)
[ERROR] TiHttpClient:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

I don't know why the bad request

Comment: output Setting.server+"/interface/about_us" to the console and copy that in your device browser, does the url work ?

Comment: I already solved the problem, replace the "post" to "POST" ,and then it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem, replace the "post" to "POST" ,and then it works